# Why does not the current version of MathJax support \delimiterfactor?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mathjax

How to verify, which version of MathJax is used here? It seems that v. 2.5 is not implemented yet.  It has very useful features, as `\delimiterfactor`, which is needed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284809/getting-large-braces-in-mathjax

Comment: I retagged as bug, since [MathJax is supposed to support delimiterfactor by now](https://www.mathjax.org/mathjax-v2-5-now-available/).

Comment: Tangentially that linked question was off-topic on [tex.se] as indicated in a comment there: "Sadly MathJax is off-topic here,[...]".

Answer (score 4):

MathJax does not implement the `\delimiterfactor` control sequence, but does have an internal value for `delimiterfactor` (the default value of 901 from TeX) that it uses in its computations for stretchy delimiters.  That value can be set from Javascript, but not from within a TeX expression.  One reason for this is that MathJax doesn't implement the localization of changes within braces, so changes to `\delimiterfactor` would be global.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-click any formula, like this one: $\int_0^1 e^x\,dx$
2. Choose "About MathJax"
3. You will see the version. Currently MathJax v2.6.0-beta.2

Comment: Thank you! +1 now and will be accepted after  some period, if no better answer appear.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question about \delimiterfactor, though. I looked around and could not find any details or examples about its use in MathJax. It just doesn't seem to be recognized. I don't know, but this might be a regression in 2.6 beta.

Comment: So, I retagged your question as a bug and I suggest not accepting any answer until the situation is clear.